# how to extract username from ldap using regex and java

Tags: java, regex

I have a text which looks like this:

```
CN=BillNameOne,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com
CN=MaryNameTwo,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com
CN=BillName,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com
CN=MaryName,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com
```

How can I extract the usernames from the string in java using regex. And I want username which start with Bill.

What should be the regex? 
I can extract username with this but how do I choose usernames which start with Bill?

```
"CN=(.*?),"
```

Comment: simply with `"CN=(Bill.*?),"`

Comment: @greedybuddha: You can achieve case insensitivity by `CN=((?i)bill[^,]*)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CN=(Bill[^,]*)` should suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
^CN=(Bill[^,]++)
```

For example

```
final String[] strings = {
    "CN=BillNameOne,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com",
    "CN=MaryNameTwo,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com",
    "CN=BillName,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com",
    "CN=MaryName,OU=departmentOne,OU=departmentTwo,DC=domain,DC=com",};
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^CN=(Bill[^,]++)");
for (final String string : strings) {
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if(matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
BillNameOne
BillName
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on knowing that a CN= is in there. Use javax.naming.ldap.LdapName, extract the rightmost RDN, and get its value. Then all you need is String.startsWith(). No RE required at all.